# Camel Spring JMS Selector

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jms, selector

We are using Camel Spring DSL and we use JMS selector in camel. But I am not able to use more than one JMS selector. If I set only one JMS selector then Its working fine. Please help on this.

camel JMS URL = camelJmsBean:topic:paymentT?durableSubscriptionName=XX_CLIENT&subscriptionDurable=true&selector=paymentSystem='pay'

How to add 2 more JMS selector in the same above URL ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMS selector syntax supports AND as well as OR. Looks like you need a compound selector.. selector=paymentSystem='pay' or paymentSystem='foo'

ref: [JMS Selector syntax](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/Message.html)

Comment: Thanks Matt Pavlovich, There is small correction required as " is not accepted by Camel spring DSL. 

camel JMS URL = camelJmsBean:topic:paymentT?durableSubscriptionName=XX_CLIENT&subscriptionDurable=true&selector=paymentSystem='pay' AND paymentSystem='foo'

Comment: off course Matt Pavlovich, Its working perfectly. Thanks for giving me correct  suggestion .